# Why does LinkedIn's organizationalEntityShareStatistics endpoint return -1 for values in certain requests?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using the organizationalEntityShareStatistics endpoint but noticed that certain requests will return -1 for a value. Is this another way of indicating `null`? For example, the following request for my personal organization returns a `shareCount` of `-1`.

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A35526437`

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "totalShareStatistics": {
        "shareCount": -1,
        "uniqueImpressionsCount": 434,
        "clickCount": 25,
        "engagement": 0.029905178701677606,
        "shareMentionsCount": 0,
        "likeCount": 10,
        "impressionCount": 1371,
        "commentMentionsCount": 0,
        "commentCount": 7
      },
      "organizationalEntity": "urn:li:organization:35526437"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "count": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "links": []
  }
}
```

I have also noticed this happening when querying share statistics for a specific share but I cannot provide that specific request because it is client data.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the format for retrieving stats on an individual post? The docs say to do `&shares[0]=urn:li:share:shareid` but I get an error on "shares[0]" https://stackoverflow.com/q/55847112/1207649

Comment: Update: I figured my own issue out (answer in my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to reference their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics#share-statistics-data-schema) for the likeCount:

> This field can become negative when members who liked a sponsored share later unlike it. The like is not counted since it is not organic, but the unlike is counted as organic.

[MRW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNOhH.gif)

...so I would assume this also applies to shareCount and who knows what other fields as well.