# LinkedIn: How do I retrieve statistics for specific shares using the organizationalEntityShareStatistics endpoint?

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn's API V2 docs specifically addresses this scenario on their [Organization Share Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics#retrieve-statistics-for-specific-shares) page, but I keep getting an error when trying a request based on their sample.

**LinkedIn's sample request:**

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics
        ?q=organizationalEntity
        &organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:2414183
        &shares[0]=urn:li:share:1000000
        &shares[1]=urn:li:share:1000001
```

**My request (from a REST client):**

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics
        ?q=organizationalEntity
        &organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A(my org id)
        &shares[0]=urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A(my share id)
```

**The response:**

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/shares[0]]",
    "status": 403
}
```

I have also tried URL-encoding the square brackets (same error) and dropping the `[0]` from the param (error "Invalid value type for parameter shares"). Does anyone know the proper way to format this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: the proper format is

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics
        ?q=organizationalEntity
        &organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A(my org id)
        &shares=List(urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A(my share id))
```

Comment: OMW.. spent so much time on this now.. So their docs are wrong?

Comment: happy 3 year anniversary of this API having terrible support

Comment: It is still better than what Facebook has. Dirt is better than what the FB API and app review process

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin API doesn't follow http standards

multiple queryparams with same key should be used as
shares=value1&shares=value2