# Organizational Entity Share Statistics is returning negative fields

Tags: postman, linkedin-api, negative-number

When I use Organization Share Statistics API via Postman it returns some negative fields. Please, could someone help me?

Query:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?shares=urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3Axxxx&q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3Axxx```

Output json:

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "totalShareStatistics": {
                "shareCount": -2,
                "clickCount": 0,
                "engagement": 0.0,
                "likeCount": -5,
                "impressionCount": 0,
                "commentCount": 0
            },
            "share": "urn:li:share:xxxxx",
            "organizationalEntity": "urn:li:organization:xxxxx"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "count": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "links": []
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics
it states: `likeCount: Number of likes. This field can become negative when members who liked a sponsored share later unlike it. The like is not counted since it is not organic, but the unlike is counted as organic.`

Comment: you're right regarding like count (thank you and sorry, i had no seen it), but shareCount field is negative too. Do you know if shareCount  can be negative too?

Comment: I am not an expert on this API and the sharecount description is not so comprehensive. Still, I would expect the same behavior. Apparently in this question the OP ahs the concluded the same (share count can be negative accordingly to link count description) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572641/why-does-linkedins-organizationalentitysharestatistics-endpoint-return-1-for-v